# How to modify previous git branch

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-branch

I have 3 git branches - Develop, QA and Master. Developers use the Develop branch for all development. Once a task is completed by a developer and the code is committed to the Develop branch, the commit is merged to the QA branch for testing. After testing is complete, the code is merged to the Master branch then deployed.  We just found a bug in the QA branch that must be fixed before deploying. The fix has been made in the Develop branch but also includes changes that we do not want to deploy at this time. So, how do we fix the bug in QA? My first thought was to make changes directly to the QA branch just to fix the issue then merge those changes back to the Develop branch. But I wasn't sure what problems that may introduce to the Develop branch (ie. lost code etc...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Git you can use `cherry-pick` to just move some commits from one branch to another.

Documentation is mentioned here:
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick

However `cherry-pick` should be an **exception** rather than **a rule**, primarily because it can lead to solving more problems.

Ideally I would advise about re-thinking your branching strategy. You can use feature branches derived from the baseline. i.e. if a bug was found on QA, then make a branch from QA, fix it and then merge it to QA and then to dev. The following link can help you get started: http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

> My first thought was to make changes directly to the QA branch just to fix the issue then merge those changes back to the Develop branch

This thought is valid and correct. We have followed it in a very active project without many problems, mostly if your changes are atomic, git is intelligent enough to merge it automatically for you. In case of conflicts, most IDEs now have support for good 3 way merge.

Answer (score 0):

If there is one commit in the Develop branch that fixes the problem, you can check out the QA branch and run

```
git cherry-pick <commit-id>
```

The `cherry-pick` action takes the set of changes made by an arbitrary commit and applies them to the current branch as a new commit. If you later merge Develop into QA, git is smart enough to avoid double-applying these changes.

Of course, be aware that cherry-picking a commit will not necessarily work cleanly. Be prepared to manually merge conflicts if they arise, and definitely test the QA branch code extensively after applying the cherry-picked commit!

If the commit that fixes the problem also contains other changes that you don't want to apply to QA, then you'll need to split that commit before cherry-picking. There are other questions on this site about how to do that.